# Extended Firefox use causes my sound to cut out

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, audio

I have [Dell](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/opgx520/en/ug/mtspecs0.htm#wp1133451) PC, and I use Windows XP.

After using Firefox for extended periods, my audio starts cutting out, as though someone is pressing play and pause continuously, and the mouse pointer lags.

The only thing that seems to help is restarting the computer.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why tagged firefox? And I think you will need to provide more detail to get a specific answer, this could be anything ranging from a virus to simply overheating.

Comment: because this happens oten when i use firefox for browsing for a long time and i find cbu consuming increase

Comment: What happens if you close Firefox? Does the problem go away?

Comment: No, may be after a period of time of closing the firefox

Comment: I have same problem on my laptop. I re-install and update my sound driver + update FireFox to last version. For now I don't have problems. What did you try so far ?

Comment: I update my firefox. but don't try to update my driver , cause i think the last update on DELL web site is old (the same i have)!